# Question score histogram by tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, score

I was wondering if it is possible to compile a histogram of *question scores* grouped by the dominant tag (i.e. the language); say for the first 10 or 20 most used tags. Or, if that's too much, a simple count of zero-score vs non-zero score questions.

I figured this might be a nice indicator for how people use SO across various fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably get the data [from SEDE, like so](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120609/frequency)

Throw that into your preferred graphing tool... job done?

(note that for simplicity, I'm not specifically handling the "dominant" tag... just things it is tagged with)

Comment: Yes, something like that -- thanks!